# Move SSH key from Ubuntu to Mac

Tags: git, macos, ubuntu, ssh

I am switching from Ubuntu to Mac and I (think I) need to move my SSH key from Ubuntu `.ssh` folder somewhere to Mac.

Trying to Google for some easy solution didn't work. [Migrate SSH keys from Linux to Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871030/migrate-ssh-keys-from-linux-to-mac) didn't help much either.

Is there any standard way of doing this?

Comment: Typically, one would regenerate the key so that it's apparent which computer did what and when.  Why do you *want* to do this?

Comment: The SO link you mention is exactly what you want. After copying your ~/.ssh folder to the mac like @Schwern answer says, you will want to also add the keys to the `ssh-agent` via `ssh-add` like the article you linked says.

Comment: @Makoto So, the best way is to generate a completely new key? I think I tried to _add_ public key and maybe that was the reason _add_ didn't work for me (the message was `Load key "id_rsa.pub": invalid format`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're files. Copy them like any other files. `scp` or `rsync` or use a USB key. Just don't do something that would hand them to a 3rd party like emailing them to yourself.

Macs are Unix machines and use OpenSSH just like Ubuntu and it all basically works the same. So you'd place your keys in `~/.ssh/` just like on Ubuntu.

The only catch is to [make sure the permissions are correct](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder#215506).

Comment: Thanks. Was thinking about copying, but I wasn't sure about OS differences and there isn't .ssh folder on my Mac - so I guess I'll just have to create one myself, directly or with some special bash command?

Comment: @Gishas Generally it gets created the first time you run `ssh`. ssh to anywhere, whether or not you login. This will ensure it has the right permissions.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to ssh to linux from mac and get the keys in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I manage many linux VMs and need to use git from any of them. I also like to be able to ssh. Having the same ssh keys on all of them means that I only need to upload one public key to my git server. To setup my keys on a new VM, I ssh to that VM and use `scp` to copy my keys down from another VM:

```
scp -r remoteVM:.ssh .
```

This should preserve the directory/file permissions, but its worth double-checking.

Comment: Rather than copying your private keys around, try [ssh agent forwarding](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/).

Comment: @Schwern Git was a quick example. I also ssh to and between these hosts using both the command line and through scripts. And, thanks a lot for Test::More!

Comment: Also, at my company I deal with some repos on enterprise github as well as "regular" git servers.

Comment: ssh agent forwarding is a general feature of ssh, it's not Github specific. And you're welcome.

Comment: For example, to give yourself keyed access to VM you only need to copy your public key into the VM's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`; you can do this safely with `ssh-copy-id`. Then if you need your private keys while logged into the VM (say to access a Git repository or another VM) rather than copying them to the VM you can access them via ssh key forwarding.